# History management problem in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I created a simple page with an UpdatePanel, inside that I have a couple of asp Panel controls, all with the Visible property set to false except for one. When the user clicks on some buttons on the side menu, the Visible property switches between the Panels being displayed, giving the user the cool & slick ajax feel.

On the scriptManager I have EnableHistory set to true.
I added history points to save which Panel is displayed each time.
I added the OnNavigate event that switches the Panel visible's property according to the previous history point.

For some reason this doesn't work, and I don't have any error/exceptions...?!?
When I try to change the Page.Title property for example in the OnNavigate event, this works perfectly, but for some reason, changing the visibility of other controls doesn't...

Any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply changing the visibility of the panels and not retrieving new data via an AJAX call (you didn't specify), remove the UpdatePanel, replace the Panel controls with standard DIVs (not running at server) and just use JavaScript to hide and show the DIVs. If you ARE retrieving data in the AJAX call, then we'll have to think of something else ;)